# Redirect User back to Page on Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise to handle user authentication. I've put a sign in form in another controller view. When a user logs in through this form, I want to redirect them back to that page. I've tried accomplishing this with the following:

Application Controller

```
after_filter :store_location

def store_location
    return unless request.get? 
    if (request.path != "/users/sign_in" &&
        request.path != "/users/sign_up" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/new" &&
        request.path != "/login" &&
        request.path != "/signup" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&
        request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&
        request.path != "/users/sign_out" &&
        !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
      session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
    end
  end



def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if request.referer == streams_url(page: params[:page])
      session[:previous_url] || root_path
    else 
     root_path
    end
  end
```

The issue with this code is when a user accesses a link from an external source, or types in the full address of the page, it doesn't work. I need a solution that works every time a user uses this specific form to log in.

Comment: After log in why you want to redirect back to login page?

Comment: After a user logs in from this form, they should be redirected back to the stream URL they logged in from, not the root path.

Comment: try `redirect_to :back`

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. if a user comes from that specific URL, I want to execute certain actions in the controller.

Comment: try    redirect_to request.url

Comment: actually, this works. The only thing is I need to execute an action after a user logs in though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    sign_in_url = new_user_session_url
    if request.referer == sign_in_url
      super
    else
      stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
    end
  end
```

add above in application_controller. If last request will be sign in then it will call parent request.

Comment: No, what needs to happen when a user logs in via this form on this page, they need to be sent back to that page on successful login. this is redirecting to the root_path.

Comment: what is your sessions#new url? is it new_user_session_url?

Comment: try to use binding.pry before `if request.referer == sign_in_url` and check what is request.referer?

Comment: This is actually working. The only thing is I need to also execute an action.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a before_filter :authenticate_user! in your application controller, you should store your location using a before filter. Also make sure you place in before the authenticate_user!

```
before_filter :store_location
```